# Discord Bot not responding to commands... (Using Pycord)

Tags: python, discord

Im trying to make a discord bot, and I want its first command to be pretty simple, I just want it to respond "pong!" when someone types "!ping" but when I try to run the command, nothing happens.. I've tried using other commands too but they all result in errors.. I'm a beginner to using Python, so please, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code, and how I can fix it?

In short, my bot doesn't respond back when I type the command I made for it to do so.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

case_insensitive=True

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix="!",
  intents=discord.Intents(members=True, messages=True, guilds=True)
)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as {0.user}!'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
      
@bot.command(name="ping", description= "Find out!")
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Pong!")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@bot.command` you should use `@client.command`.

Also no need for the `from discord.ext.commands import Bot` import

So your new code would be

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

case_insensitive=True

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix="!",
  intents=discord.Intents(members=True, messages=True, guilds=True)
)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as {0.user}!'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
      
@client.command(name="ping", description= "Find out!")
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Pong!")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it provided me with another error about client not having an attribute, command. Here's the error message if you'd like to see it.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    @client.command(name="ping", description= "Find out!")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Answer (score 0):

You could just do inside `on_message` code block

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!ping'):
        await message.channel.send('Pong!')

client.run('your token here')
```